# Compose a CAML Query to Query an SPList with Managed Metadata Column

Tags: c#, sharepoint-2010, caml

I have an SPList with a managed metadata column and here is my caml query.

```
/// This caml query doesn't work
SPQuery oQuery = new SPQuery();
string strQuery = @"<Query><Where><In><FieldRef LookupId=""TRUE"" Name=""TaxonomyColumn"" /><Values><Value Type=""Text"">7392ec1d-3f35-4c5b-b6ad-f80ff15ed718</Value></Values></In></Where></Query>";
oQuery.Query = strQuery;


/// This linq query works exactly fine
var itms = (from SPListItem itm in oList.Items
        where itm["TaxonomyColumn"].ToString().Contains("7392ec1d-3f35-4c5b-b6ad-f80ff15ed718")
        select itm).ToList();
```

My problem is I need to use CAML Query for some reason and I can't just figure out a way on how to compose my CAML Query to work on querying a list where the column is a managed metadata column.

Please help me. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't use the GUID, you need to use the lookup the id. You find this id using TaxonomyField.GetWssIdsOfKeywordTerm(), and write CAML like this:

```
<Query>
  <Where>
    <In>
      <FieldRef LookupId="TRUE" Name="ItemType" />
      <Values>
        <Value Type="Integer">14</Value>
        <Value Type="Integer">15</Value>
      </Values>
    </In>
  </Where>
</Query>
```

"In" is a convenience when there are multiple values instead of multiple Eq/Or statements.

Explained in detail here:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff625182.aspx

Comment: http://sharepointfordeveloper.blogspot.com/2012/05/sharepoint-2010-using-in-operator-in.html

End tags missing </Values></In>.  Even Microsoft examples have these tags missing, and everyone copies and pastes it like it works (and people even accept it as the working answer, which is even more baffling).

Without these end tags I get a runtime error as expected, about these end tags being missing.

Answer (score 0):

SPQuery adds the Query tag itself:

```
 SPQuery oQuery = new SPQuery();
string strQuery = @"<Query><Where><Contains><FieldRef Name='TaxonomyColumn' /><Value Type='Text'>7392ec1d-3f35-4c5b-b6ad-f80ff15ed718</Value></Contains></Where></Query>";
oQuery.Query = strQuery;
```

Comment: I've already tried that before I posted this question and 100% doesn't work. Looks like this is the end of the world for me. hahaha